# Tomcat startup Process taking too much memory

Tags: java, kubernetes, tomcat, containers

After migrating our codebase from JDK 8 to JDK 17 and upgrading our tommee server from version 7 to 8, we've observed a notable increase in memory usage within our Kubernetes container, leading to frequent Out of Memory (OOM) occurrences. The primary culprit behind this surge in memory consumption is identified as the Tomcat process.

Here's a snippet of the Java process that is responsible for consuming a significant portion of the container's memory:

```
java --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -javaagent:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/app/etc/webapp/log4j2.yaml --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=java.lang,javax.security,java.util,org.apache.activemq,somePackage,someOtherAppPackage -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=n -Xms32m -Xmx256m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=printf '{"v":"1.1.1","category":"SERVICE","level":"FATAL","timestamp":"%s","application":{"name":"%s","version":"%s","component":"OutOfMemory","thread":"localhost-startStop-1","instanceId":"%s","process":"%s"},"details":{"type":"INTERNAL","description":"Out of memory error"}}\n' 2023-12-11-T19:23:19.999Z MyApp Version containers %p -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -DAsyncLoggerConfig.RingBufferSize=32768 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath :/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/bval-jsr-2.0.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina-ant.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina-ha.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina-ssi.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina-tribes.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/catalina.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-cli-1.5.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-codec-1.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/cryptacular-1.2.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/cxf-rt-rs-mp-client-3.5.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/cxf-shade-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/ecj-4.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/el-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-config-impl-1.2.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-health-1.0.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-health-common-1.0.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.6_mail-1.0.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-metrics-1.0.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-metrics-common-1.0.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-openapi-impl-1.0.12.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-opentracing-1.0.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/geronimo-transaction-3.1.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/howl-1.0.1-1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/hsqldb-2.7.1-jdk8.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-annotations-2.15.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-core-2.15.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-databind-2.15.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.15.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jasper-el.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jasper.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jaspic-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jasypt-1.9.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/java-support-7.5.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/javaee-api-8.0-6-tomcat.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/joda-time-2.10.10.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/johnzon-core-1.2.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/johnzon-jaxrs-1.2.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/johnzon-jsonb-1.2.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/johnzon-jsonp-strict-1.2.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/johnzon-mapper-1.2.20.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jose4j-0.9.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jsp-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/mbean-annotation-api-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-config-api-1.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-fault-tolerance-api-1.1.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-health-api-1.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-jwt-auth-api-1.1.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-metrics-api-1.1.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-openapi-api-1.1.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-opentracing-api-1.1.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/microprofile-rest-client-api-1.3.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/mp-common-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/mp-jwt-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/myfaces-api-2.3.10.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/myfaces-impl-2.3.10.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/neethi-3.0.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-api-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-client-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-core-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-cxf-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-cxf-rs-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-cxf-transport-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-ejbd-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-hsql-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-http-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-jee-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-jee-accessors-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-jpa-integration-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-loader-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-rest-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-server-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openejb-webservices-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openjpa-3.2.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-core-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-profile-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-saml-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-saml-impl-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-security-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-security-impl-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-soap-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xacml-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xacml-impl-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xacml-saml-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opentracing-api-0.31.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xacml-saml-impl-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/opensaml-xmlsec-impl-3.4.6.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-ee-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-ee-common-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-ejb-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-el22-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-impl-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-jsf-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-spi-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/openwebbeans-web-2.0.27.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/org.osgi.annotation.versioning-1.0.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/quartz-openejb-shade-2.2.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/safeguard-impl-1.2.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/serp-1.15.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/servicemix-bcel-shade-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/servlet-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/snakeyaml-2.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/stax-ex-1.8.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/swizzle-stream-1.6.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/sxc-jaxb-core-0.8.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/sxc-runtime-0.8.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/taglibs-shade-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-cs.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-de.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-ko.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-pt-BR.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-ru.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-jni.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-util.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-catalina-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-common-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-config-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-jaxrs-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-jdbc-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-loader-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-microprofile-webapp-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-mojarra-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-myfaces-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-security-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/tomee-webservices-8.0.15.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/txw2-2.3.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/websocket-api.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/woodstox-core-6.4.0.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-bindings-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-policy-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-ws-security-common-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.4.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xbean-asm9-shaded-4.22.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xbean-bundleutils-4.22.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xbean-finder-shaded-4.22.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xbean-naming-4.22.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xbean-reflect-4.22.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xmlschema-core-2.2.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/xmlsec-2.3.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/yoko-osgi-1.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/yoko-rmi-impl-1.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/yoko-rmi-spec-1.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/yoko-spec-corba-1.4.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/disruptor-3.4.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-core-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.14.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-jul-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/log4j-web-2.17.1.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/lib/unified-log-format-5.5.5.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/app/lib/tomee/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/app/lib/tomee -Dcatalina.home=/opt/app/lib/tomee -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/app/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

This Java process includes various configurations and agents, contributing to its memory footprint. To address the OOM issues, we need to investigate and optimize the Tomcat and Java configurations to ensure efficient memory utilization in the updated environment.

Not much sure about the above issue,can you provide insights into the potential causes behind the observed increase in memory usage in your Kubernetes container after the migration? Additionally, what solutions have you considered or implemented, aside from the straightforward approach of increasing container memory?

From the vm log we see

```
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: [   4514]  1000  4514      370        5    36864        0           993 docker-entrypoi
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: [   4542]  1000  4542   527958   134250  1490944        0           993 java
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=cri-containerd-f5d9c1fd0408c6b34ec25cf2231b12982c4ec8a4e53acbd13640c18a278e8a04.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod449e988f_9640_4af7_8db4_6db8189250fd.slice/cri-containerd-f5d9c1fd0408c6b34ec25cf2231b12982c4ec8a4e53acbd13640c18a278e8a04.scope,task_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod449e988f_9640_4af7_8db4_6db8189250fd.slice/cri-containerd-f5d9c1fd0408c6b34ec25cf2231b12982c4ec8a4e53acbd13640c18a278e8a04.scope,task=java,pid=4542,uid=1000
Dec 13 10:20:25 ip-some kernel: Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 4542 (java) total-vm:2111832kB, anon-rss:511524kB, file-rss:25476kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1456kB oom_score_adj:993
```

It is the Java OOM and The process which is taking more time is the tomcat one which I mentioned above .

Comment: Any reason to upgrade to JDK17, but Tomcat only to 8 (actual version is 11) ? TC 8 EOL March 2024.

Comment: You should probably take a thread dump and analyse the memory usage.

Comment: @PeterMmm you mean heap dumps

Comment: Hello, we migrated to tomee version 8 for now, but soon we will be migrating to a higher version in  few months. Regarding taking heap dump, their is no leak we already analyzed, it's just that tomcat startup process is running which is consuming quite a lot of memory which is causing container restart.

Comment: @PeterMmm TomEE version 8 means Tomcat 9, so there is no worry about Tomcat EOL.

Comment: Your JRE launch parameters shown in the question do not include any memory-related parameters. Check for `-Xms` and/or `-Xmx` and add them to the question. When you get OOME, is that a Java OOME or is that an OS OOME? If you take a heap dump as Peter/aled suggest, you should be able to see what is taking up all of that heap space.

Comment: I have updated the full jdk parameter and also the vm log for reference

Comment: Another point to add here, java heap memory space is not getting fullied but the total physical memory that is excedding. This is happening after migrating our application from jdk8 to jdk17 and tomee version from 7 to 8